# Question about idempotents.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $B=A/\operatorname{rad} A$, where $\operatorname{rad}A$ is the radical of $A$ (intersection of all maximal right ideals of $A$).  Let $e$ be an idempotent of  $A$ and $\bar{e}=e+\operatorname{rad} A$.

I have some difficulty in understanding the proof of (c) of Proposition 4.5 of the book (page 21)[Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

On line 8 of the proof (c) of Proposition 4.5, it is said that $eA = e_1 A \oplus \{(1-e_1)A \cap eA\}$. Here $e_1 = (g_1t)^m, g_1 \in eA$ such that $\bar{e}_1 = g_1 + \text{rad} A$, $\bar{e}_1, \bar{e}_2$ are idempotents of $B$ such that $\bar{e}=\bar{e}_1B \oplus \bar{e}_2B$. How to prove $eA = e_1 A \oplus \{(1-e_1)A \cap eA\}$? Why we know that $eA \cap e_1A = 0$? Thank you very much.

> [image]

Comment: $\dim_K(A)<\infty$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, that as well as $K$ algebraically closed is a general assumption in that book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know that $eA\cap e_1A=0$ because that is not true. To the contrary we want to prove that $eA=e_1A$.

What they do is that they intersect the left and the right hand side with $eA$. For the left hand side it is obvious that the result is $eA$. For the right hand side note that since $e_1\in eA$ we have that $e_1A\subseteq eA$. Now we can apply the modular law (i.e. that if $L\subseteq N$ then $(L+M)\cap N=(L\cap N)+(M\cap N)$, which is easy to prove elementary) to get the wanted equality.

Comment: thank you very much. I am trying to show that $e(1-e_1)A=eA \cap (1-e_1)A$. If $x \in eA \cap (1-e_1)A$, then there are $y, z \in A$ such that $x=(1-e_1)y=ez$. So $x=e(ez)=ex=e(1-e_1)y \in e(1-e_1)A$. Now suppose that $x \in e(1-e_1)A$. Then there is some $a \in A$ such that $x=e(1-e_1)a$. We know that $ee_1=e_1$. But we do not know that $e_1e=e_1$. So we do not have $x=e(1-e_1)a=(1-e_1)ea$. How can we show that $x=e(1-e_1)a \in (1-e_1)A$? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JianrongLi Changed my argument to an easier one.

Answer (score 0):

We will show that if $e\in A$ is idempotent, i.e. $e^2=e$, then $B=eB \oplus (1-e)B$ for any $A$-module $B$.
Let $x\in B$. Then $x=1\cdot x=(e + (1-e))x=ex + (1-e)x$, so $B=eB+(1-e)B$. Moreover $eB\cap (1-e)B=0$ since $e(1-e)=e-e^2=e-e=0$.